# Showing symmetric and antisymmetric tensor series are inverses in $K(M)[[t]]$?

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and let $K(M)$ denote its real $K$-theory ring, following Remark 2.7 at the [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+K-theory#the_kgroup).

Given a vector bundle $V$ we define the quantities
$$
S_t(V) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (S^jV)t^j 
\;\;,\;\;
\Lambda_t(V) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (\Lambda^jV)t^j 
$$
valued in $K(M)[[t]]$. (I assume $S_t(-V)$ and $\Lambda_t(-V)$ would be defined in the expected ways, by e.g. "absorbing the minus signs into $t$".)

---

I am trying to show that $S_t(V) \cdot \Lambda_{-t}(V) = 1 \in K(M)[[t]]$, for any $V$. (This is stated in e.g. the 3rd page, written as p. 31, in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-174/issue-1/Modular-invariance-and-characteristic-numbers/cmp/1104275092.full).)

Following the suggestions in Prop 2.10 of the topological K-theory nLab page, I was able to reduce the above to showing that for any integer $\ell \geq 1$ and any (non-virtual) $V$ there is some other (non-virtual) vector bundle $F$ such that
$$
F \oplus \left( \bigoplus_{\substack{0\leq j \leq \ell , \\ j\text{ even}}}
    S^{\ell-j}V \otimes \Lambda^{j}V
\right)
\simeq 
F \oplus \left( \bigoplus_{\substack{0\leq j \leq \ell , \\ j\text{ odd}}}
    S^{\ell-j}V \otimes \Lambda^{j}V
\right) .
$$

However here I am stuck. I was wondering if anyone could help explain why the above is always true, for some $F$? (Following the suggestions at the nLab page, if $M$ is compact we should be able to find such an $F$ which is also trivial.)